# scala sbt cache x eclipse build path

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I'm added a dependence to my build.sbt (casbah). I did a sbt update, I did check my ~/.ivy2/cache directory and all jars are there. Do I have to add this ~/.ivy/cache directory to my Build Path and add the casbah as external Jar to my project? If no, probably no because I did try it, what should I do to be able to use this jar in my scala project?

**EDIT**

I found this instructions that helped me, but still a hack

1. Establish a simple project (general/project) named "IvyCache" 
   located at your ".ivy2/cache" folder just for library reference 
   purposes.
2. Establish a Scala project located at your "project" folder.
3. Add the following libraries to the Scala project by means of "Add 
   JARs" to the "Java Build Path":

   3.a) All jars from "/IvyCashe/org.scala-tools.sbt" filterred by 
   "*2.9.1-0.11.2" or any other Scala/SBT version numbers.

   3.b) A single sbinary_*.jar from "/IvyCache/org.scala-tools.sbinary".

   3.c) A single test-interface*.jar from "/IvyCache/org.scala- 
   tools.testing".

Now your build files should compile within Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to manage this is to use the [eclipse plugin for sbt](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse).  Then you can just say `sbt eclipse` on the command line any time you change the dependencies in build.sbt, and the Eclipse files will be automatically updated for you.

Doing it this way means that you will never have to manually configure your Eclipse build path.  After all, sbt already knows how to construct the build path, so there's no reason you would have to do it manually.